# Nginx + PHP-FPM is very slow on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, nginx, php

I have set up Nginx with PHP-FPM on my MacBook running ML. It *works* fine but it takes between 5 and 10 seconds to connect when I run a page in my browser. Even the following PHP script:

```
<?php
die();
```

takes about 5 seconds to connect. I am using Chrome and I get the "Sending request" message in the status bar for around 7 seconds. If I refresh again it seems to work instantly, but if I leave it for around 10 seconds it will "sleep" again. It is as if nginx or PHP is going to sleep and then taking ages to wake up again.

Edit: This is also affecting static files on the server so it would seem to be an issue with DNS or nginx.

Can anyone help me figure out what is causing this?

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 2;

events {
   worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
   default_type text/plain;
   server_tokens off;
   sendfile on;
   tcp_nopush on;
   keepalive_timeout 1;
   gzip on;
   gzip_comp_level 2;
   gzip_proxied any;
   gzip_types text/plain text/css text/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss;

   index index.html index.php;

   upstream www-upstream-pool{
      server unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
   }

  include sites-enabled/*;
}
```

php-fpm.conf

```
[global]
pid = /usr/local/etc/php/var/run/php-fpm.pid
; run in background or in foreground?
; set daemonize = no for debugging
                         daemonize = yes

include=/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/pool.d/*.conf
```

pool.conf

```
[www]
user=matt
group=staff
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_requests = 500
listen = /tmp/php-fpm.sock
;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
php_flag[display_errors] = off
```

sites-available/cft

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name cft.local;
   root /Users/matt/Sites/cft/www;
   access_log /Users/matt/Sites/cft/log/access.log;
   error_log /Users/matt/Sites/cft/log/error.log;
   index index.php;

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }

   include fastcgi_php_default.conf;
}
```

fastcgi_php_default.conf

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

location ~ .php$
    {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED   $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

    fastcgi_pass www-upstream-pool;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
}

fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: You really need to work harder on pinning down the source of the problem: If you access static files hosted on nginx, does this behavior occur? If you launch a PHP script from the command-line with php, does this occur?

Comment: I have been trying! PHP works fine and as normal from CLI. The issue is also happening with static files, which would suggest an nginx problem.

Comment: See? That is something important. It means you can throw away any references to PHP in your post. We can't help you without that kind of info.

Comment: @MattHumphrey could you please update the question with the contents of any files located in the `sites-enabled` directory? Since you are able to serve static contents, you must have a `server {}` definition somewhere, and that is the missing piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @plasmid87 Thanks for the reply, I have updated.

Comment: What's happening when you are requesting `http://127.0.0.1/index.php` rather than `http://site.local/index.php`? (Might need to set `server_name = _;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One reason could be - as already suspected above - that your server works perfectly but there is something wrong with DNS lookups.

Such long times usually are caused by try + timeout, then retry other way, works, cache.

Caching of the working request would explain why your second http request is fast.

I am almost sure, that this is caused by a DNS lookup, which tries to query an unreachable  service, gives up after a timeout period, then tries a working service and caches the result for a couple of minutes.

> Apple has recently made a significant change in how the OS handles requests for ".local" name resolution that can adversely affect Active Directory authentication and DFS resolution.
>
> When processing a ".local" request, the Mac OS now sends a Multicast DNS (mDNS) or broadcast, then waits for that request to timeout before correctly sending the information to the DNS server.  The delay caused by this results in an authentication failure in most cases.

http://www.thursby.com/local-domain-login-10.7.html

They are offering to set the timeout to the smallest possible value, which apparently is still 1 second - not really satisfying.

I suggest to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 or try http://test.dev as a local domain

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost test.dev
```

**EDIT**
In OSX `.local` really seems to be a reserved tld for LAN devices. Using another domain like suggested above will def. solve this problem

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3473

**EDIT 2**
Found this great article which exactly describes your problem and how to solve it

http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2012/07/os-x-lion-and-local-dns-issues.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response, unfortunately it is still happening now I have changed the hostname to cft.dev

Comment: Did you try 127.0.0.1 just to make sure we're on the right way?

Comment: The issue in the end was all down to my host file entries being on separate lines. It should look like: 127.0.0.1 localhost cft.dev site.dev etc. Many thanks for your help and research, Michel.

Comment: Wow. sometimes it's just a single character which costs us sleepless nights. glad I was able to help

Comment: To summarize **make sure that you use a single 127.0.0.1 entry** solved this for me _with Mavericks_

Comment: Just wanted to tell that this answer was helpful ! I had a 5 second timeout delay while I was using .local domain.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see anything in your configuration that would cause this behaviour alone. Since the configuration of Nginx looks OK, and this affects both static and CGI request, I would suspect it is a system issue.

An issue that might be worth investigating is whether the problem is being caused by IPv6 negotiation on your server.

If you are using loopback (127.0.0.1) as your listen address, have a look in `/etc/hosts` and ensure that the following lines are present:

```
::1    localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
::1    site.local cft.local
```

If this doesn't resolve the issue, I'm afraid you'll need to look at more advanced diagnostics, perhaps using [strace](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples/) or similar on the Nginx instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "not to be recognised at all"? Did you append the entries to `/etc/hosts` or replace existing entries? You should avoid replacing existing entries and simply append the above.

Answer (score 0):

(this started as a comment but it's getting a bit long)

There's something very broken here - but I don't see anything obvious in your config to explain it. I'd start by looking at top and netstat while the request is in progress, and checking your logs (webserver and system) after the request has been processed. If that still reveals nothing, then next stop would be to capture all the network traffic - most likely causes for such a long delay are failed ident / DNS lookups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had looked at top already and both nginx nor php-fpm do not even flicker when I refresh the page.. Although I have noticed there are 3 nginx instances being displayed under top.. is this normal? I think it is definitely a DNS issue. I have pow installed also, could they be conflicting?

Comment: I dont think it's pow. My local domain name is site.local and that is pointing to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file. Is that the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Usually 127.0.0.1 would be localhost (or localhost.localdomain). If your CPU usage and load are low / unnaffected by web activity then it's a problem with blocking (file contention in your php code / DNS lookup / ident issue / problem in firewall config). Have a look at the network activity.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what you mean by looking at network activity? Also, interestingly it takes just as long with pow so it is definitely a port 80 / DNS / network issue...

Comment: @Matt Humphrey The number of instances depend on your workers setting. n workers + 1 master, while n is defaulting to 2 - so, yes, this is normal

Comment: No - your looking for DNS requests from your server and ident lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Barring any configuration-related issues, it may be a compile issue.

I would advise that you install nginx from homebrew, the OS X open source package manager.

If you don't yet have homebrew (and every developer should!), you can grab [it from here](https://brew.sh) or just run this in a terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Then run

`brew install ngnix`

And ngnix will be deployed from the homebrew repository. Obviously, you'll want to make sure that you removed your old copy of nginx first.

The reason I recommend this is that homebrew has a number of OS X-specific patches for each open source library that needs it and is heavily used and tested by the community. I've used nginx from homebrew in the past on OS X and had no problems to speak of.

Comment: @Matt in that case, compile it yourself and deploy.

Comment: @Mahmoud Isn't homebrew already compiling packages on the local machine?

Comment: @Michel yes, but sometimes not stock.